# Unable to install SDRPlay RSP1A with GNU Radio Companion

Tags: gnuradio

I'm attempting to use an SDRPlay RSP1A with Gnu Radio, but the standard SDR sources blocks don't work.
The RSP1A is however successfully working with SDRconnect on Windows 10
GnuRadio is version 3.10.8.0
SDRplay API is version 3.14

The windows workflow documented here
https://www.sdrplay.com/docs/gr-sdrplay-workflow.pdf
seems straightforward, but I believe it is out of date and not suitable for gnuradio 3.10 and V3 of the API

So, I have been attempting to install Franco Venturi's OOT gr-sdrplay3 following the instruction in the above link. I have downloaded the package from github
https://github.com/fventuri/gr-sdrplay3
and have attempted to build under as instructed using cygwin

```
cd gr-sdrplay3
mkdir build && cd build && cmake .. && make
sudo make install
```

However, this fails as follows when attempting the make

```
Steve@Bhup /cygdrive/d/AmateurRadio/Install/RSP1A_SDR_GnuRadio/gr-sdrplay3-main
$ mkdir build && cd build && cmake .. && make
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Build type not specified: defaulting to release.
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Success
-- Found Threads: TRUE
-- Found Boost: /usr/include (found suitable version "1.66.0", minimum required is "1.65") found  components: filesystem program_options regex thread system chrono date_time atomic
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:105 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindGnuradio.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Gnuradio",
  but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Gnuradio"
  (requested version 3.10) with any of the following names:

    GnuradioConfig.cmake
    gnuradio-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Gnuradio" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Gnuradio_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Gnuradio" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
```

Line 105 or CMakeLists.txt is
find_package(Gnuradio "3.10" REQUIRED)

so it would seem something is missing. I'm not particularly adept at Makefiles and the build procedure, and am at a total loss to know how to fix this.

To be clear, I have not compiled GNU radio, just downloaded the Windows install package. GNU Radio appears to be otherwise perfectly functional.

Ideally of course I would just prefer to somehow acquire a compiled version of the gr-sdrplay3 OOT for Win 10 and not have to compile anything, but I've been unable to find this

If this is not an appropriate place for this question, then please advise.

Answer (score 0):

After considerable research and with much help from Franco Venturi, the only viable way I could find to get a RSP1A, or indeed any SDR Play device to work with GNU Radio, was to follow the instructions on the following page to the letter. This does involve installing some packages that may seem unnecessary, but it does work. Franco provides a binary that simplifies the installation somewhat.

See
https://github.com/fventuri/gr-sdrplay3/blob/conda/WINDOWS.md